# How can I neatly align the output of string variables?

Tags: java, string, output

I am printing the three columns of strings. How can I organize the output with the first column string size being completely random and  make it not distort the distances between columns?

I dont know many java class methods. I am fairly new to java as well as software development in general.


SOURCE:

```
//just printing out the data with the string I built "String p"
//don't mind dividing them into three strings



         while (true) {
                        tok = lex.nextToken();

                        String p = TokenType.tokens.get(tok.getKind()) + 
                                   "    left: " + tok.getLeftPosition() +
                                   " right: " + tok.getRightPosition() + "  ";

                          if ( (tok.getKind() == Tokens.Identifier) ||
                              (tok.getKind() == Tokens.INTeger) || 
                               (tok.getKind() == Tokens.FLoat) )
                             p += tok.toString();

                        System.out.println(p + " line:"+lex.source.getLineno() );

                    }
```

Here is sample output to give some ideas. 

I at least want the second column to be aligned.


OUTPUT:

```
READLINE:   program if == float f
program    left: 0 right: 6   line:1
if    left: 8 right: 9   line:1
==    left: 11 right: 12   line:1
float    left: 14 right: 18   line:1
<id>    left: 20 right: 20  f line:1
```

Comment: Use  something like \t (tab) before left and right so that you can align.

Comment: Aajan , thanks works good.

Comment: This is a simple solution. But doesnt really meet what I am asking for. I am asking how to align them. Not ever second column string will be perfectly aligned. The solution is good enough for my program though.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), or the underlying [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
System.out.printf("%-10s left: %-2d right: %-2d  %-3s line: %d%n",
                  TokenType.tokens.get(tok.getKind()),
                  tok.getLeftPosition(),
                  tok.getRightPosition(),
                  (tok.getKind() == Tokens.Identifier ||
                   tok.getKind() == Tokens.INTeger ||
                   tok.getKind() == Tokens.FLoat ? tok.toString() : ""),
                  lex.source.getLineno());
```

Remove the `-` signs to right-align.